# Error:Could not initialize class com.android.sdklib.repositoryv2.AndroidSdkHandler

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, build

I want to build this [project](https://github.com/AnySoftKeyboard/LanguagePack) with Android Studio at launching, but take a error. Stacktrace is [here](http://pastebin.com/XkGKpSMy)

Comment: Please, fix your grammar, show your project setup, etc.

Comment: @Eldelshell, wich specific configurations you want to see?

Comment: Please don't link to external resources, include all relevant info directly in the question.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

This problem occurs when there are multiple JDKs installed in your system, I had the same issue as I had mistakenly installed oracle-jdk-9 and Android studio requires oracle-jdk-8

If you are using Ubuntu you can install jdk-8 from [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/521145/how-to-install-oracle-java-on-ubuntu-14-04).

So, Make following changes as shown below:

Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> that will open project structure which can also be opened from

> File -> Project Structure

And then change JDK Location where you may have installed JDK 8

[image: Here is the link to image]

Answer (score 24):

this because your classpath build tools in build.gradle root project is deprecated update like this for new android studio 3.2.0

```
buildscript {
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0-alpha14'
}
```

and after that update your minimum sdk and build tools to latest and no problem again

Answer (score 14):

I had the same problem. I had installed Java 8 and Java 9.
I set `JAVA_HOME` to Java 8, but Gradle was using Java 9.

I changed the JDK in File->Project Structure to Java 8 and it worked.

Answer (score 8):

JAVA 9 has forcefully taken over the JAVA_HOME to itself.

after installing java9 you will find

```
# java -version
java version "9.0.1"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9.0.1+11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9.0.1+11, mixed mode)
```

So instead of uninstalling java 9 let us point the JAVA_HOME back to java 8

First find out the Android studio embeded JRE location

and add an entry in ~./bash_profile at last

```
export JAVA_HOME="/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home"

# source ~/.bash_profile
# java -version
java version "1.8.0_151"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_151-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.151-b12, mixed mode)
```

source
http://scalebean.blogspot.com/2018/01/fix-gradle-could-not-initialize-class.html

Answer (score 7):

Changing the JDK in Android Studio to point back at 8 didn't work for me. I uninstalled Java 9 and this solved the issue.

Answer (score 6):

**One simple solution:**

React-Native isn't compatible with Java 9 or Java 10

**Resolve this issue by simply downgrading to Java 8**

Comment: Been trying every other solution in an attempt to build react on Java 10... your simple solution saved me further hours of work, thank you!

Comment: Ok, but how to do it? Incomplete answers doesn't help at all

Answer (score 3):

Go to **build.gradle**,
and make sure your **gradle dependencies** up to date.
For Android studio 4.2.2 
dependencies { 
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2'
.........
.........
}

Answer (score 2):

If you have several Javas in Ubuntu, you can

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
sudo update-alternatives --config javac
```

to select the Java 8 that Android and Gradle need.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is having issues with IntelliJ IDEA, go to `File` -> `Project Structure` (or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>) and remove all JDK 9 entries. JDKs are marked under `Platform Settings` -> `SDKs` with a folder behind a tiny blue cup of coffee.

I tried adding the correct path to JDK 1.8 but IntelliJ IDEA will default back to JDK 9 for whatever reason. Unfortunately, I need JDK 9 for other projects, so uninstalling it would be too much of a hassle. If you need to use JDK 9 for another project (like I do), you can still add a JDK 9 entry via the same menu and then remove it again when required.

Answer (score 0):

If the Problem Persists, just import the gradle to Android Studio and build the file inside the Android Studio.

Android Studio automatically handles gradle and sdk problems.
After successful build you can also try running the app via `react-native run-android` in the 
*Command Prompt*. Hope this Helps.
This was the only fix that fixed this issue.
I tried all the above answers but problem persisted

Comment: The OP seems to be building the project inside Android Studio already.