# React Native; SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable

Tags: android, react-native

This error came up when run react-native run-android.

I have already setup environment variables.

`ANDROID_HOME C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk`

I tried creating `local.properties` file in in `myapp/android`
with the content of this, `sdk.dir = C:/Users/ivani/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk`.

This error came up.

> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
>   Could not initialize class com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler

Comment: This may seems to be a duplicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39679997/9038584

Comment: This Link will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37513651/errorcould-not-initialize-class-com-android-sdklib-repositoryv2-androidsdkhandl

Answer (score 0):

Go to Control Panel > System and Security > System click on Advance System Setting > Environment Variable > System Variable > Edit > New
Add the path i.e C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools and click ok.

Set the ANDROID_HOME and JAVA_HOME path go to Control Panel > System and Security > System click on Advance System Setting > Environment Variable > User Variable > New
set the SDK path click ok and set the jdk path click ok

for further reference follow the step 5 and 6 from [React Native Environment Setup on Windows 10](https://medium.com/@prasadjivane/react-native-environment-setup-on-windows-10-47a3b5e833b9)

Comment: Better to write the solution here in the answer, than giving a link to the solution

Comment: @DarkSuniuM I have added the solution in the blog. Step 5 and 6.

Comment: Adding it here as well is more useful

Comment: I hope this is what you where expecting. Thanks for your valuable comment @DarkSuniuM