# How i can reapirt problem in new flutter project

Tags: flutter, dart

When i create new flutter project and click run i have this problem

"Could not initialize class com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YgZlI.png)

Flutter doctor
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cR8h7.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error:Could not initialize class com.android.sdklib.repositoryv2.AndroidSdkHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37513651/errorcould-not-initialize-class-com-android-sdklib-repositoryv2-androidsdkhandl)

Answer (score 0):

1. go to Android/build.gradle.
2. if jCenter() exist try this change:

   ```
   buildscript {
       ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
       repositories {
           google()
         jCenter()   // change this to mavenCentral()
       }

       dependencies {
           classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
           classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
       }
   }

   allprojects {
       repositories {
           google()
          jCenter()   // change this to mavenCentral()
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Not working....

Answer (score 0):

Run this in the console: `flutter clean`

Comment: Not working....