# Run old github android java project in android studio

Tags: java, android

I have this github file https://github.com/udacity/ud843-QuakeReport and you can clone it from https://github.com/udacity/ud843-QuakeReport.git , but the problem is , my android studio doesn't know how to run it .

What to do  ?

I just get this simple error saying

```
Could not initialize class com.android.sdklib.repositoryv2.AndroidSdkHandler
```

I didn't do any change in the code, it is google udacity code, and trusted to work in all situations.

How to run my project now ?

Comment: What version of Android Studio are you using? The project uses Android Gradle Plugin v2.1.0 which is very old and [unsupported by modern versions of AS](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#android_gradle_plugin_and_android_studio_compatibility). You can try to download older version of AS (e.g. 2.1) and open the project with it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error:Could not initialize class com.android.sdklib.repositoryv2.AndroidSdkHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37513651/errorcould-not-initialize-class-com-android-sdklib-repositoryv2-androidsdkhandl)